# Detect Input text length in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am beginner in Angularjs

```
<div ng-app>
  <input type="text" ng-model="Number"/>
</div>
```

I know can use {{Number.length}} to display input field length,
But how detect length 
etc..

```
if (length == 0) {
  // do something
} else if (length == 1) {
  // do something
}
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

### 1. Using built-in directives + template

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <input type="text" ng-model="Number"/>
      
    <section ng-if="!Number">It's empty</section>
    <section ng-if="Number">It's {{Number.length}}</section>
</div>
```

You could also use a controller or directive to achieve the same thing.
See some examples in action -> http://jsbin.com/vaxohi/4/edit

### 2. Using a controller

You can watch the value of `Number` in a controller, like so:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.Number = '';
  $scope.$watch('Number', function(newValue){
     if(newValue.length === 0){
       console.log('Empty');
     } else {
       console.log('Has content');
     }
  });
});
```

However, it's not a good practice to do it like this. The best way to do it is by using a directive.

### 3. Using a directive

Diretives can attach certain behavior to DOM elements; there are many built-in directives (`ng-if`, `ng-show`, etc), but it's very common to create custom ones. Here's an example:

```
app.directive('numberLogic', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    template: "<input type='text' ng-model='Number2'/> {{Number2}}",
    link: function(scope){
      scope.$watch('Number2', function(newValue){
        if(newValue.length === 0){
          console.log('Second number Empty');
        } else {
          console.log('Second number Has content');
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

#### By the way...

I see your `ng-app` directive is empty. Don't forget to pass in a module name for your app `ng-app="appName"` and define a module with the same name `angular.module('appName', []);` (See the jsbin).

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/duketopmost/0zdwLcdx/4/)
why length !=0 can't type +
Can anyone Help

Answer (score 1):

you can use  **ng-change**

for example

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Number" 
ng-change="(Number.length>0)?alert('ok'):alert('no')"/>
```

or you can specify an function to be executed on change

```
<div ng-app="app">
     <div ng-controller="test">
<input type="text" ng-model="Number" 
    ng-change="checkLength()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And Js code

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('test',function($scope){
     $scope.checkLength = function(Number){
    if(Number.length>0){
    //
    }
}
})
```